# Magento2 "something went wrong while saving cart price rule update"

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using `Magento 2.1.3` **Enterprise Edition**, and when I try to add a new update for the Cart Price Rule like below:

> Marketing -> Cart Price Rule -> Schedule New Update or Click on Edit
>   already exist update from list -> then open the action tab only not
>   conditions -> save

Then after it I am receiving the following error:

> Something went wrong while saving the
>   Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface.

Can you please help me to know what is the issue/

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know it's problem is in the javascript. But we can also solve it like this by overriding the default save in your module di.xml

```
  <preference for="Magento\SalesRuleStaging\Controller\Adminhtml\Update\Save" type="Namespace\CustomPromo\Controller\Rewrite\SalesRuleStaging\Adminhtml\Update\Save"/>
```

Save.php is

```
namespace Namespace\CustomPromo\Controller\Rewrite\SalesRuleStaging\Adminhtml\Update;


class Save extends \Magento\SalesRuleStaging\Controller\Adminhtml\Update\Save
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $stagingData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('staging');
        $entityData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if($entityData['rule'] && !isset($entityData['rule']['conditions'])){
            $entityData['rule']['conditions'][1] = unserialize($entityData['conditions_serialized']);
        }
        return $this->stagingUpdateSave->execute(
            [
                'entityId' => $this->getRequest()->getParam(static::ENTITY_IDENTIFIER),
                'stagingData' => $stagingData,
                'entityData' => $entityData

            ]
        );
    }

}
```